How to Handle Lath and Plaster Removal Near Drywall Ceiling?
I'm working on a hallway where the walls had old lath and plaster in bad shape. The ceiling already has drywall installed over the plaster and is in good condition. I plan to replace the wall lath and plaster with drywall, but I'm stuck at the wall-ceiling junction. Some lath is tucked behind the ceiling drywall, and removing it would damage the ceiling.
I should note that the lath also has to go because some studs are not plumb and are significantly out of alignment with each other, which I intend to fix but that requires removal of both plaster and lath.
Any advice on how to proceed?


You have 3 options:
1-  You can cut the lath and plaster as close as you can, ( just like shown in the pic). Then drywall, butting the top up close to the edge of the old plaster and lath.  Tape and mud that joint.  With the age of the house you may get cracks that show up, but such is the price of old and new work meeting in a house.
2- You can use crown moulding to hide the imperfections between the ceiling and walls.
3- You can take a deep breath and tear out the ceiling drywall and lath/ plaster and re-drywall everything.
